# Converting a Matlab column array into a Java Array: transposition issue

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, matrix

I know the tittle is not really clear so I am going to do my best to explain the situation here.

I have a Matlab array, say: `array = [1,2 ; 3,4]`. So basically this is a 4x4 matrix.

I have a java class which goals is to convert matlab matrixes into java arrays. This class has two constructors:

```
MatlabArray( double[] array );
MatlabArray( double[][] array );
```

And this class has one member to store the array values:

```
double[][] values
```

The class is working perfectly fine with matlab matrices ( both sizes > 1 ), matlab singletons ( 1x1 ) and matlab lines ( 1x2, 1x5 etc ...).

But when it comes to column matrices here comes a downfall, basically a line or a column matrix is still a two dimensional array, it's just that one of its dimension is 1.

When the call to the java constructor is made, the one being called end up being:

```
MatlabArray( double[] array );
```

This cause the java arrays to becomes a LINE matrix. Say I had the following Matlab matrix say: `array = [1;2;3;4]`, then the converted java array would be `array =  {1,2,3,4}`

Losing the coherence causes later crashes because the indexes used to access values in the different arrays does not match anymore.

Previously we had a workaround ( people knew when this issue was coming, and they were inverting the indexes ). Workaround which of course I got rid of.

I am looking for ideas to solve this issue in a elegant way, I could specify the dimensions in the constructor but I would rather avoid that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your constructor "MatlabArray( double[] array)" should in turn call the MatlabArray( double[][] array ). I think this should answers your question. So are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Actually It's already doing that, but it does not solve the issue: how do you differentiate between a 1 x n matrix and a n x 1 matrix since they all end up in the first constructor as a double[] ?

Comment: So do you need to distinguish between column matrix (n×1) and matlab lines (1×n)? And you are asking how to implement that in an elegant way?

Comment: If so, the more simple yet elegant way that does not compel you to change your data model, is to just add a second parameter to your double[] constructor; an enum with only two options, enum.Line and enum.Column. And change your inner data representation or accessing algorithm, depending on it.

Comment: This is a possibility which I would have liked to avoid because it forces the developer to performs tests before calling the constructor in Matlab ( the matrix could be m x n too ). While those tests can be centralized some people will duplicate it. Moreover, I noticed that calling functions have a huge impact on perfs on matlab side. Since the conversion function is highly recursive we decided to exceptionally do it in one single function (perfs ranged between 250 and 1550 times faster ... ).

Comment: However, I noticed that if I just removed the MatlabArray( double[] array ) it works perfectly fine in all cases. So I will probably go for it even if it means rewriting some part of the java code which actually needs this constructor to correctly package an array into a two dimensional array.

Comment: OK good work :)